# How to fix the error CPackage::LoadFromXML that causes the package to fail?

Tags: ssis

I had this package which been running fine since a year or more.  All of sudden it has thrown below error.  Though on restart it was success.   How to debug this issue and prevent from happening again.

```
Executed as user: xxxxx. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version
10.0.2531.0 for 64-bit Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.
Started: 7:15:08 AM Error: 2011-07-07 07:15:08.62 Code: 0xC0010018 Source:
Description: Error loading value "
    <DTS:VariableValue xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"
    DTS:DataSubType="ManagedSerializable"
    DTS:DataType="13"><SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="htt" from node "DTS:VariableValue".
End Error
Error: 2011-07-07 07:15:08.62 Code: 0xC0010018 Source:
Description: Error loading value 
    "<DTS:Variable xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts">
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Expression"></DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="EvaluateAsExpression">0</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Namespace">User</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name=" from node "DTS:Variable". 
End Error
Could not load package "d:\edw\edw\trunk\src\etlHandler\HDL\DropZoneJobHandler.dtsx"
because of error 0xC0010014.
Description: The package failed to load due to error 0xC0010014 "One or more
error occurred. There should be more specific errors preceding this one that
explains the details of the errors. This message is used as a return value
from functions that encounter errors.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.
Source: Started: 7:15:08 AM Finished: 7:15:08 AM Elapsed: 0.609 seconds.
The package could not be loaded. The step failed.
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please take a look at the following link from `social.msdn.microsoft.com` discussing about a similar error message. Hope that helps.

[**CPackage::LoadFromXML Failure**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/9b511f4c-b82c-468a-926f-cb561acdc415/)

Comment: -1 for providing link only. Particularly when its a discussion form with so many answers and don't know where to look for solution

Answer (score 19):

I have had this issue on Visual Studio 2015 when creating SSIS Packages.
To resolve it, I changed the TargetServerVersion to SQL Server and that resolved the error.

Comment: I couldn't import a password protected dtsx package into MSDB (SQL Server 2016). Turns out my VS2015 project had a default value for  TargetServerVersion of "vNext". Changing to "SQL Server 2016" allowed my package to be imported. You saved my day!

Comment: https://desk.cozyroc.com/portal/en/kb/articles/how-to-change-the-targetserverversion-property-for-an-ssis-project

Answer (score 3):

I was using SSIS package which was upgraded to SSIS 2012, and the SSMS that I was using was 2008. This was the issue that I faced, and I opened the SSMS 2012 and it stopped throwing this error.

I hope this is the case, although with what I have researched, this error could be thrown for various other reasons as well.

Answer (score 2):

For me the error came from a bad password when opening the package. It's strange because usually it just asked me to type in the password again, but since last VS2017 update, the package just fails.

Comment: Bruno, I had this password situation happen to me too.  Bad MS software development in my opinion.

Comment: Bruno, I think most of the discussion here is about a dtexec on a server where there wouldn't be a second chance for a password.  But I did get this message on a client like you are discussing.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this 0xC0010014 error when I used a VS 2017 ent build with a dtexec on a server.   I set server to SQLServer2014 and the job started to run, but for a while it would throw the 0xC0010014 at the top of the ssis log but still run successfully.   I think if you have EncryptSensitiveWithPassword you have to reset the package password after you make the SQLServernnnn change.  You have to be aware of what version of dtexec you have on the server, what version the package might have been built in originally (many packages run for years without touching them and may have been built with vs 2015 or vs 2012) and what version of VS you are building with (easier to keep a laptop up to date, maybe you have VS 2017 or VS 2019).  You might have a really current Visual Studio to do your builds, but be running in a really old server/dtexec environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by changing a connection that was referencing to one of my DSN entries that was not created.

After removing the connection, I was able to view the package and then I created a new connection after the new DSN was created.

Please let me know if you need more details and i will provide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when attempting to schedule an `SSIS` job to run using `SQL Agent`.  The error came up after I'd selected the package and clicked OK to exit the setup of the step in `SQL Agent`.

In my environment, I develop `SSIS` jobs on server A, and schedule jobs in `SQL Agent` from my local computer.  SQL is hosted on server B.

I'm usually able to schedule jobs without error using `SSMS` on my local computer.  However, this particular `SSIS` package uses the [Sharepoint List Adapater](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/), which I'd installed on server A for the `SSIS` development.

**The solution was to install that adapter on my local computer**.  I also installed it on server B, which hosts our SQL instance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this scenario was asking customer change the debug option `Run64BitRuntime` from `True` to `False`. With this `Run64BitRuntime=False` setting, all works as in 32bit mode. See below link:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/farukcelik/2010/06/16/why-package-load-error-0xc0010014-in-cpackageloadfromxml-error-appears-while-trying-to-run-an-ssis-package/

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when I try to setup Import/Export process on SQL server and save it as SSIS package. I was using excel(.xlxs) as source file.

I resolved it by installing https://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/download/confirmation.aspx?id=4438 (Access 2007 Runtime) on sever).

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project in VS 2019, added a couple tasks and tried to upload and got this error.

Solution: SQL Server was 2012 and the project was set as SQL Server 2017. Changed the project to 2012 saved everything and it worked.